did_multiplegt_dyn - base comparison time
I am using did_multiplegt_dyn in Stata to estimate the effect of a treatment.  When using an earlier version of this package (did_multiplegt), the event study plot produced used t= -1 as the baseline year for comparisons - As the package explains, "accordingly, the first placebo is shown at period -2 on the graph."
When using did_multiplegt_dyn, the event study plot produced uses t=0 as the baseline year for comparisons.
Does anyone know how to change this default did_multiplegt_dyn setting so that the estimates and event study plot use t= -1 as the baseline year for comparisons?
